# No way to color the border of a Tkinter Button?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, colors, widget

It works with some other widgets, but not with Buttons.

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x300+400+50")

btn_up = Button(root, text='Go UP')
btn_up.config(highlightbackground="red", highlightcolor="red", highlightthickness=10, relief=SOLID)
btn_up.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Python 2.7 - Windows 10

Comment: Does it error or does it just not give it a thickness with a color?

Comment: Oh, I left a `bd=3` by mistake there, I'll take it out.

Comment: It just shows the black border, no errors and no colors.

Comment: Also, `highlightthickness` doesn't work, it is displayed just the 2px border.

Comment: `highlightthickness` isn't the border. It's a separate thing. Tkinter provides no control over the border color.  Do you _really_ need to change the color of the border, or do you simply want to surround it with a line of a specific color? In other words, there may be a way to do what you want, just not in the way you want to do it.

Comment: Yeah, I could put the button within a frame with a color I guess, I was just wondering why these options I saw in the documentation weren't working. It'd be nice to have a border that isn't black, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using linux and when I run your code, I get a button with a thick red border, so it looks like that the default Windows theme does not support `highlightthickness` while the default linux theme does.

[image: screenshot]

If you want to change the border color, it is possible with some ttk themes like 'clam':

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
root = Tk()

style = ttk.Style(root)
style.theme_use('clam')
style.configure('my.TButton', bordercolor="red")

ttk_button = ttk.Button(root, text='Go UP', style='my.TButton')
ttk_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot clam]

However, changing the borderwidth, with `style.configure('my.TButton', borderwidth=10)` does not increase the width of the red border as expected.

Comment: If python 3.x, replace `Tkinter` with `tkinter` and `import ttk` with `from tkinter import ttk`.