# How do i change the colour of a button border tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

How do i change the colour of a border in tkinter

I have looked at other solutions which recommended using `highlightcolor` and `highlightbackground`, however these did not work.

```
excercises_button = Button(canvas, width=327, height=150, image=dumbell_img,borderwidth=4, relief="ridge", bg = "gray55", command = Excercises)
canvas_excercises_button = canvas.create_window(168, 724, window=excercises_button)
```

I would like the border of this button to be orange.

This is what it currently looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QX8X.png

Comment: In order to create a border you will need to add the button to its own frame and use the background color of that frame to make a different color border from the button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No way to color the border of a Tkinter Button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47352833/no-way-to-color-the-border-of-a-tkinter-button)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how one can have a kind of border created by using a frame and a button.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(root, highlightbackground="orange", highlightcolor="orange", highlightthickness=4, bd=0)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
# adding weights so the button is center on the frame.
frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

btn = tk.Button(frame,text="test", borderwidth=4, relief="ridge", bg = "gray55").grid(row=0, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: unfortunately i can't use this method as it won't work very well with my wider application. Is there no attribute or single line of code which could add a small border?

Comment: @DominicCulyer well there is not any simple way of doing this. It just doesnt exist in Tkinter. However I am sure a modified version of what I have shown you can and will work. Just takes some effort. There is more you can do with this. Like making sure that the border will always be a specific size around the widget even when resizing the window. Its just a matter of handling the configure event with the correct methods.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution!

What i did is I created a rectangle which surrounded the buttons.

```
canvas.create_rectangle(0, 638, 1100, 900, fill=colour)
```

I then made the three buttons a few pixels smaller to allow the background of the rectangle to show.

Comment: That is also a good work-around. Glad you found a solution that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is the top answer on a google search, i will share the method found on the [duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47352833/no-way-to-color-the-border-of-a-tkinter-button):
(code refactored to work with python 3.10)

```py
from tkinter import ttk,Tk
root = Tk()

style = ttk.Style(root)
style.theme_use('clam')
style.configure('my.TButton', bordercolor="red")

ttk_button = ttk.Button(root, text='Button', style='my.TButton')
ttk_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[Resulting window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8Ddy.png)
this code works because certain ttk themes allow changing the border color on buttons.