# How to change the color of the box surrounding a Tkinter Button?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, colors, border

I tried some things I found on Stackoverflow such as placing a frame around the button and giving that a color, like said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53101307/how-do-i-change-the-colour-of-a-button-border-tkinter). I also tried some other stuff that is said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47352833/no-way-to-color-the-border-of-a-tkinter-button) but I can't get it to work.

I'm using Mac OS and the buttons are rounded, but there's a square around it which makes it look not as nice. Does anyone know how I can get this square to change its color?

This is the code I'm working with:

```
empty = Button(frame, text='Opnieuw', command=clear, font=bold_font)
empty.config(width=10, fg='#009688', borderwidth=0, relief=RAISED)
empty.grid(row=11, column=0, pady=(25, 0), padx=(80, 0))
```

This is the square I'm talking about: the white one which is around the button and does not have that green color.

[image: This is the square I'm talking about]

After adding what Bryan Oakley said, by doing this:

```
empty = Button(frame, text='Opnieuw', command=clear, font=bold_font)
empty.config(width=10, fg='#009688', borderwidth=0, relief=RAISED)
empty.configure(highlightbackground="#009688")
empty.grid(row=11, column=0, pady=(25, 0), padx=(80, 0))
```

More specifically, this is a larger piece of the code I'm using:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font as tkfont

root = Tk()
root.config(background='#009688')
root.title('Contractmaker')

# GUI stuff that takes care of the scrollbar
def on_configure(event):
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'))

def on_mousewheel(event):
    canvas.yview_scroll(int(event.delta), 'units')

# Create some fonts
bold_font = tkfont.Font(weight='bold')

# Create the actual GUI
canvas = Canvas(root, width=450, height=550)
canvas.config(background='#009688')
canvas.pack(side=RIGHT)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(root, command=canvas.yview)
# scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill='y')

canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
canvas.bind('<Configure>', on_configure)
canvas.bind_all('<MouseWheel>', on_mousewheel)

frame = Frame(canvas)
frame.config(background='#009688')
canvas.create_window((0,0), window=frame)

empty = Button(frame, text='Opnieuw', font=bold_font)
empty.config(width=10, fg='#009688', borderwidth=0, relief=RAISED)
empty.configure(highlightbackground='#009688')
empty.grid(row=11, column=0, pady=(25, 0), padx=(80, 0))

root.mainloop()
```

this is what I got:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can get the white part of the button to stay white instead of also changing its color? I'm using python 3.8 and Tkinter 8.6.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem you see. For me, the code works according to the documentation and only adjusts the ring around the button. Please create a complete [mcve] so we can be sure you haven't left out details. I'm guessing it should  take less than a dozen lines of code. Also, we need to know which versoin of python and tkinter you're using.

Comment: I updated my question once again. I hope I provided the information needed. Looking forward to your answer, thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure but that is a bug, it goes away if you focus out and focus back to the main window. For example try open a `Toplevel` window in the same program then click on toplevel window and then back on the main window.

Comment: I still see a white button on my mac, though I'm running python 3.7 and tkinter 8.5.

Comment: I think it is a bug indeed as Saad mentioned because after clicking on some random stuff in the GUI, it sometimes shows the correct button as Bryan Oakley showed in his answer.

Comment: Which appearance you have dark or light? if light, then change to dark and let us know if the tkinter window goes black and show nothing.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with appearance and dark / light. Like how the button is displayed? I see it dark when opening it but then after clicking some stuff, it sometimes goes light.

Comment: @BryanOakley: i think you can reproduce the issue with **Tcl 8.6 & Tk 8.6 (8.6.8)** on any python 3.x version

Comment: I mean system dark/light mode. See [here](https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/enable-dark-mode-macos-mojave/) how to change.

Comment: @Saad, I had it dark mode. After changing it to light mode, nothing changed. The colors change when I focus on a different app and then go back to my GUI. After that first focus change, the color keeps changing between in-focus and out-focus, which is good I guess. But when my GUI opens, it looks like the screenshot I showed which makes it seem as my GUI is out of focus.

Comment: How are you writing your code like in which ide? and are you using any python environments? Can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55516222/10364425) solve your issue?

Comment: I'm using PyCharm. I have no clue actually whether I'm using any environments so I don't think I am. I took a look at the page you suggested but I don't really understand what they're saying. Guess I'll make a new question about my GUI not being focussed visually. Thanks a lot for your time and answers!

Comment: For anyone in the future who has the same problem, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62609543/my-tkinter-gui-seems-visually-out-of-focus-when-opened) is the question regarding the focus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That white area is called the *traversal highlight region*. It changes color to let the user know when the button has the keyboard focus.

You can change its non-focused color with the `highlightbackground` option, and its focused color with `highlightcolor`. You can set it to the color of the background to get it to blend in.

```
empty.configure(highlightbackground="#009588")
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I didn't know we could do that on macOS. ***Quick question:-*** How can we do the same with `ttk.Button`? I tried to map as well as configure with `ttk.style` but it doesn't work.

Comment: If I do this, the entire button gets a shade of that color. I will update my question with a picture.